# Redirect to specific link once I click on 'SharePoint' text in top left corner

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was wondering if it is possible to redirect to root site or a specific link whenever I click on 'SharePoint' text in top left corner of the main top bar (Kindly check attached picture).

Currently, whenever I click on it, it redirects to the main layout of followed and frequent sites.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint start page has a purpose. It gives you an alternative to using a physical structure developed by your organization to access sites based on your activity. We can't point to another SharePoint URL instead of the Start Page because it's there for a reason.

Comment: I added a home site before to enable Global Navigation and it works when I click on 'home' icon. However, it doesn't work when I click on 'SharePoint' text in the top left corner above the home icon. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, what I have answered previously was wrong. I have just updated it.